# DATE_ADD() is not working in MySQL XDev API with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mysql-connector, mysql-x-devapi

In MySQL shell I am able to run

```sql
select * from meeting where startTime > date_add(now(), interval 2 day);
```

This same command is not working using [MySQL XDev API](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/)

```js
var meetingRows = (await sqldb.getTable('meeting').select().where('startTime > DATE_ADD(NOW(), interval 2 DAY)').execute()).fetchAll()
```

I am getting error

```
-- PARSING FAILED --------------------------------------------------

> 1 | DATE_ADD(NOW(), interval 2 DAY)
    |                          ^

Expected one of the following: 

'!=', '%', '&&', '&', '*', '+', ',', '-', '/', '<', '<<', '<=', '<>', '=', '==', '>', '>=', '>>', '^', 'and', 'between', 'div', 'in', 'is', 'like', 'not', 'or', 'overlaps', 'regexp', '|', '||'

    at _.tryParse (/usr/src/app/node_modules/parsimmon/src/parsimmon.js:928:15)
    at Object.parse (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/lib/ExprParser/index.js:46:27)
    at Object.getValue (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/lib/DevAPI/ProjectedSearchExprStr.js:88:27)
    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/lib/DevAPI/Table.js:276:95
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.select (/usr/src/app/node_modules/@mysql/xdevapi/lib/DevAPI/Table.js:276:18)
```

What is wrong in my code? How can I make this working?

Comment: what's with the backticks around the where argument?

Comment: backtick is just to create string. I have changed backtick to single quote

Answer (score 0):

```
const mysqlx = require('@mysql/xdevapi');

const session = mysqlx.getSession({
  user: 'your_user',
  password: 'your_password',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 33060,
  schema: 'your_schema'
});

const meetingTable = session.getSchema('your_schema').getTable('meeting');
const now = mysqlx.expr('NOW()');
const interval = mysqlx.expr('INTERVAL 2 DAY');

const meetingRows = await meetingTable
  .select()
  .where(mysqlx.expr('startTime > :startTime', { startTime: now.add(interval) }))
  .execute()
  .fetchAll();

console.log(meetingRows);
```

Comment: I am getting error `now.add is not a function`. Is it working for you?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, with an X DevAPI expression, you should be able to use a simplified flavour of that SQL statement:

```
NOW() + interval 2 DAY
CURDATE() + interval 2 DAY
```

So, you can use the API like the following:

```
.where('startTime > NOW() + interval 2 DAY')
```

In practice, I think it's not really working, so you can still use the regular SQL with `session.sql()`.

I suggest you report a bug at https://bugs.mysql.com/ using the `Connector for Node.js` category.

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI connector for Node.js